# Filtering Windows Messages in a Hook Filter Function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I am trying to retrieve messages for another application with a Windows hook.  I have setup a WH_GETMESSAGE hook with SetWindowsHookEx.  This is done via a DLL.  In my GetMsgProc function (that should be called whenever the target application receives a message) I want to take action based on the type of message.  However I am having trouble with this if statement.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHookProcedure(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    if(((MSG*)lParam)->message == WM_COMMAND){
        MessageBox(NULL,L"The hook procedure was called",L"Test Window",MB_OK);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(g_MessageHook,code,wParam,lParam);
}
```

For some reason the MessageBox is never created. I know the application is receiving WM_COMMAND messages from Spy++.  If I take out the IF statement the MessageBox is created over and over as it receives a variety of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're hooking the correct window or the correct message, respectively? Under some circumstances `WM_SYSCOMMAND` or `WM_MENUCOMMAND` is generated instead of `WM_COMMAND`.

Your code looks fine, have you also tried dumping the incoming messages into console?

Comment: I think you are right, I must be hooking the wrong window.  I will check my logic.  Thanks for looking at my code.

Answer (score 0):

The LPARAM here is a pointer to CWPSTRUCT which in turn contains message parameter. The following should work.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHookProcedure(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    if(((CWPSTRUCT*)lParam)->message == WM_COMMAND){
        MessageBox(NULL,L"The hook procedure was called",L"Test Window",MB_OK);
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(g_MessageHook,code,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: Your comment helped too.  I actually got the functionality I needed with a WH_CALLWNDPROC hook which uses the CWPSTRUCT as you mentioned. I also was hooking the wrong window. :)  Thanks for the help!