# Fiddler-like program for OS-internal requests

Tags: windows, fiddler

Fiddler captures HTTP requests and responses so that you can examine them and debug them. What tools are out there that deliver a similar sort of functionality but for OS-internal requests and responses? Specifically I'm looking for a program that captures Windows-internal calls -- and if none exist, this would be a good opportunity to understand what I don't understand about how the Windows OS works.

For example, Fiddler has a button that says "View in Notepad" which lets you examine a response in Notepad. I want to know what command is executed here in the background that in fact opens up Notepad with the response text in it. I am guessing it should look something like `notepad | $text`.

Comment: [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is probably the closest to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, there is a **message loop**

Some links about it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues

http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/NET/NETtip54.asp

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33459/%2FArticles%2F33459%2FSpying-Window-Messages-from-the-Inside

A message loop will catch any command, but it works only for your thread. When you write a minimal Windows program in C++ like in the first link, you set up a window and a message loop and catch whatever WM_command is intended for your window.

Other messages that go around inside Windows, intended for other processes can be **hooked** when you run with admin permissions. This may give you some snippets,

[Filtering Windows Messages in a Hook Filter Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875950/filtering-windows-messages-in-a-hook-filter-function)

Hope this will help to roll your own hooks. I have no idea if free software exists that does this.